# NSCalendar dateFromComponents returns strange date

Tags: ios, calendar

The NSCalendar dateFromComponents function returns unexpected date.
Here is the use case :

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
[calendar setTimeZone:timeZone];
```

Where timezone is: Local Time Zone (Europe/Paris (GMT+1) offset 3600)

```
NSDateComponents *finalComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:now];
[finalComponents setWeekday:weekDay];
```

At this point, I have the following value for `finalComponents` :

    Calendar Year: 2018
    Hour: 23
    Minute: 59
    Week of Year: 1
    Weekday: 2

The `[calendar dateFromComponents:finalComponents]` returns `2018-12-31 22:59:00 +0000` and I expect `2017-12-31 22:59:00 +0000`

Any help is welcome

Comment: Yes duplicate, sorry the solution in the response above works

Comment: @SlumTheSlug - that solution has fixed value for `components.yearForWeekOfYear = 2015` Will it work foreever/next year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this help you..!

Note: I used value for weekday as `1` (for IST it gives me correct date). You can update it according to your timezone.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
[calendar setTimeZone:NSTimeZone.localTimeZone];

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *finalComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:currentDate];
[finalComponents setWeekday: 1];
[finalComponents setYearForWeekOfYear:finalComponents.year];  // Update year dynamically here

NSLog(@"Current Date: %@",currentDate);
NSLog(@"Print Date: %@",[calendar dateFromComponents:finalComponents]);
```

> **Current Date: Fri Jan  5 20:00:53 2018**
>   
> **Print Date: Sun Dec 31 20:00:00 2017**

Ask me, if you need any further help..!

Answer (score 0):

The components that you extract seem to be ambiguous, resulting in a weird date. If you include the `NSCalendarUnitYearForWeekOfYear` in your selected components, you should get the correct year:

```
NSDateComponents *finalComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekday | NSCalendarUnitYearForWeekOfYear fromDate:now];
```

For me adding the extra component makes it so that I get the correct year.